# Are ES6 features compiled to ES5 when used within TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

When I use ES6 features like for example template string, arrow functions, destructuring within a TypeScript file. Afterward I compile the file to normal JavaScript ...

**Are the ES6 syntax compiled too by the TypeScript compiler? Or do I have to use an additional compiler (Babel)?**

Comment: use babel for es6

Comment: It depends - see `--target` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Yes, they are, if proper `target` is specified. Some of them are supported for `es5` only in recent versions (`async` function) or aren't supported at all (`new.target`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need additional compilers that downport your code from ES6 to ES5.

TypeScript is pretty smart and will do most of the work for you (i.e. translate `let` to `var` or arrow functions to standard functions with right scope and bindings).

EDIT: as @Paleo pointed out, on 99% you don't need any external compiler as you can provide to TypeScript an extra library (polyfill) which makes everything work fine.

You will need an extra compiler on very rare cases when you are not covered neither by transpiler nor by polyfill's.

Comment: No, the API `Promise` on old browsers doesn't require Babel, but just a polyfill. I added an answer.

Answer (score 8):

> **Are the ES6 syntax compiled too by the TypeScript compiler? Or do I have to use an additional compiler (Babel)?**

I disagree with the Fylax's answer. The TypeScript compiler doesn't require an additional tool for converting the ES6 syntax to ES 3 or 5.

The TypeScript compiler tranpiles the new syntax (`let`, `for … of`, arrow functions, rest parameters, etc.) to ES 3 or 5. But it doesn't provide any polyfill by itself. In order to use a recent API (like `Promise`) on a old VM ES 3 or 5, you have to:

1. Load a polyfill (like [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)) that makes the API available;
2. Say the compiler to use the standard typings for this API.

It is a robust design option. With typeScript, you have to choose carefully the polyfills you need, and to test them on the different browsers you target.

By default, when the target is ES 3 or ES 5, the compiler doesn't use the definitions for the recent ECMAScript API. See [the documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Note: If `--lib` is not specified a default library is injected. The default library injected is:
>
> ► For `--target ES5`: `dom,es5,scripthost`

If a polyfill makes an API available, then we can configure the compiler to use it. Here is an example of configuration file `tsconfig.json` for using promises on ES5 VM:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2015.promise"]
  }
}
```

However, Babel can convert a few more features to ES 5 than TypeScript does. See [the compatibility table from Kangax](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: I was not aware of es6-promise polyfill so thank you. Anyway my answer should be read as "it depends". On most cases you can save yourself just changing the target, sometimes you need a polyfill, sometimes babel. The point to my answer was: on some very rare case you need it.